# How to change column name in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and I think I need a little help. I'm trying to rename the column heading in `ItemDistributedStatus`, `AssignedTo`, `AssignedDept` to just `STATUS`, `ASSIGNED TO`, `DEPARTMENT` but the `AS 'column Name'` doesn't take effect on them since I think they already have the AS from the `CASE` query.

So I'm just not sure how to do it, already tried enclosing it with () and I'm just getting error.

Here's my query code.

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN ItemDistributedStatus = 0 
        THEN 'Available' 
      WHEN ItemDistributedStatus = 1 
        THEN 'Assigned' 
   END AS ItemDistributedStatus, 
   SerialNum AS 'SERIAL', 
   ModelNum AS 'MODEL', 
   ItemType AS 'TYPE', 
   BrandManufacturer AS 'MANUFACTURER', 
   CASE 
      WHEN AssignedTo IS NULL 
        THEN '-' 
        ELSE AssignedTo 
   END AS AssignedTo, 
   CASE 
      WHEN AssignedDept IS NULL 
        THEN '-' 
        ELSE AssignedDept 
   END AS AssignedDept, 
   DateAssigned AS 'DATE'
FROM    
   TblItemDetails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE When ItemDistributedStatus = 0 
            then 'Available' 
         When ItemDistributedStatus = 1 
            then 'Assigned' END     AS [STATUS] 
        ,SerialNum                  AS [SERIAL] 
        ,ModelNum                   AS [MODEL] 
        ,ItemType                   AS [TYPE] 
        ,BrandManufacturer          AS [MANUFACTURER] 
        ,ISNULL( AssignedTo, '-')   AS [ASSIGNED TO] 
        ,ISNULL( AssignedDept, '-') AS [DEPARTMENT] 
        ,DateAssigned               AS [DATE]

From    TblItemDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it already.
:D

```html
SELECT CASE When ItemDistributedStatus = 0 then 'Available' When ItemDistributedStatus = 1 then 'Assigned' END as 'STATUS', 
  SerialNum AS 'SERIAL', 
  ModelNum AS 'MODEL', 
  ItemType AS 'TYPE', 
  BrandManufacturer AS 'MANUFACTURER', 
  CASE When AssignedTo IS NULL then '-' Else AssignedTo END as 'ASSIGNED TO', 
  CASE When AssignedDept IS NULL then '-' Else AssignedDept END as 'DEPARTMENT', 
  DateAssigned AS 'DATE'
From TblItemDetails
```